# Oscillation in number of deaths by coronavirus

Tags: data-visualization

Looking the graphs that report the number of deaths by coronavirus in worldometer, I have noticed that for many countries there is a clear oscillation with a one week period.
See for example the graph for the UK and the US:

[image]
[image]

Why do you think this is happening? It seems to me that for some reason, the number of deaths is under-reported during the weekends.

Comment: That's exactly the reason: no reporting during the weekend. It is for both reported new cases and reported deaths. You can also see a bump in the subsequent Monday.

Comment: I asked because I found odd that nobody is mentioning it: newspapers discuss these numbers day by day like if they are always meaningful.

Comment: The second question is: why they do not report all the deaths during the weekend? Don't they have something in place that automatically sends this information ? I understand that this is not a question for this forum.

Comment: Dear Marco, I am not sure but I suppose that it's a practical matter, in the sense that is usually a delay between the actual deaths/infected detection and reporting. As this article  report "Many hospitals will not report deaths that happened over the weekend until the middle of the following week." source bbc: https://www.bbc.com/news/health-52167016. I hope this clarifies things! Best!

Comment: PS where did you find the moving averaged plots? They are nice!